# Using the Paypal sandbox to test an application

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I recently set up Paypal payments standard on my web app and things are working fine.  I am able to use Paypal sandbox to test and things work the way I expect.

However, I would like to send out the app to my beta testers and allow them to test making payments without actually using their Paypal accounts or credit cards.  I can create sandbox merchants and sandbox payees, but that doesn't quite do it.  My button send them to sandbox.paypal.com... but when they get there they are asked to log in with a developer/sandbox password.  It doesn't just let them login with the test payee account.

I can work around this, but I wanted to see if I was missing something.

Comment: The sandboxes were build for developers, not clients.

Comment: @Mike, if you read question clearly, he wants test sandbox with testers and testers are not clients !!

Answer (score 0):

Ya this type of situation was not what we intended the sandbox to be used for. Every sandbox account is tied to a developer account so there is no way around this.

You can do your unit testing or test your application in sandbox, and go live to actually have your clients start using it. There was no plan to have your clients test making payments in sandbox.